Modify Woocommerce order status on custom date from ACF field
We have an ACF field added to Woocommerce orders storing date on which reminder should be sent to customers (text field with date in d/m/Y, field ID 'reminder'). Would like to change order status on that date to identify orders where reminders have been sent. I have found and modified a piece of code that I hope we can use, but struggle with how to access and pull in the date from the custom ACF field to trigger order status change.
Can you please help my modify the query part to use date from the order ACF field? Thanks in advance for any help!
function order_status_changer() {

    global $wpdb;

    $result = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT * 
    FROM  $wpdb->posts
        WHERE post_type = 'shop_order'
        AND post_status = 'wc-processing'
");


    $args = array(
        'date_query' => array(
            array(
                'column' => 'post_modified_gmt', // post modifed one month ago
                'after' => '1 month ago',
            ),
        ),
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_reminder_sent', // skip posts that is already updated in last run
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
            )
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'shop_order',
        'post_status' => 'wc-processing', // slug of your status to modfiy
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);


    $posts = $query->posts;

    foreach ($posts as $post) {

        $ord = new WC_Order($post->ID);
        $ord->update_status('wc-reminder-sent'); // Slug to which these order to be updated
        update_post_meta($post->ID, '_reminder_sent', 1); // update posts meta to note the status change for skipping on next read
    }
}
order_status_changer();


Pls, try the following code. It should fulfill your requirement
 // Register new shop order status
 function register_order_status() {
    register_post_status( 'wc-reminder_sent', array(
      'label'                     => 'Reminder Sent',
      'public'                    => true,
      'exclude_from_search'       => false,
      'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
      'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
      'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Reminder Sent (%s)', 'Reminder Sent (%s)' )
 ) );
   
 }
 add_action( 'init', 'register_order_status' );

  function add_custom_order_status( $new_order_status ) {
   $new_order_status = array();
   // add new order status
   foreach ( $order_statuses as $key => $status ) {
     $new_order_status[ $key ] = $status;
     if ( 'wc-processing' === $key ) {
        $new_order_status['wc-reminder_sent'] = 'Reminder Sent';
     }
    }
   return $new_order_status;
}
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'add_custom_order_status' );

add_action( 'woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta', 'custom_func_wc_process_shop_order_meta' );
function custom_func_wc_process_shop_order_meta( $order_id ){
   $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
   $order->update_meta_data( '_reminder_sent', wc_clean( $_POST[ '_reminder_sent' ] ) );
   $order->update_status('reminder_sent');
   $order->save();
 }

 add_action('admin_head', 'styling_admin_order_status' );
 function styling_admin_order_status() {
   global $pagenow, $post;
   if( $pagenow != 'edit.php') return; // Exit
   if( get_post_type($post->ID) != 'shop_order' ) return; // Exit
   ?>
   <style>
    mark.order-status.status-reminder_sent {
        background: darkturquoise;
        color: #000;
    }
   </style>
  <?php
 }

Additional Code:
// Function to change order status on given reminder date
function change_order_status_toreminder_date() {
 // Get all orders
 $orders = wc_get_orders( array(
    'status' => array( 'processing' ), 
    'limit' => -1,
 ) );

 foreach ( $orders as $order ) {
   $reminder_date = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'reminder', true);
   // If reminder date matches current date
   if ( $reminder_date && $reminder_date === date( 'Y-m-d' ) ) {
      // change order status to reminder_sent
     $order->update_status( 'reminder_sent' );
   }
 }
}

// Schedule event to check reminder dates daily
function schedule_event_to_change_order_status() {
 if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'event_to_change_order_status' ) ) {
   wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'event_to_change_order_status' );
 }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'schedule_event_to_change_order_status' );

// Hook into scheduled event
add_action( 'event_to_change_order_status', 'change_order_status_toreminder_date' );

Note: Add the above code in child theme's functions.php file

Thank you, but I can't see where in the provided code we include the order change trigger - we want to change order status to 'reminder sent' on specific date defined in order's ACF field

@user3767576 in the given code, I used the woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta action hook to change the order status to 'Reminder Sent' if reminder date is set. So, add the code in child theme and try to change the reminder date and click Update order button.

tried testing but while the status changes if the date is set, I'd like it to change only on the date that's set in the custom field...

@user3767576 I have added some additional code to change the order status automatically on the given reminder date. Please check. Hopefully, it will help
